# Is there a Possuk in Tanach that starts with a Samech ס and ends with a Aleph א?

Tags: tanach, names, aleph-bet-letters

I have a relative with the name סימא and she has been unable to find a Possuk in Tanach that starts with a Samech ס and ends with a Aleph א. Is there such a Possuk? The lists that are elsewhere do not have a verse that begins with a Samech and ends with an Aleph.

Comment: did you check the back of the artscroll siddur? Cause none exists there.

Comment: did you try searching one of the Torah programs that can check for you?

Comment: Although many _sidurim_ include _p'sukim_ for only some of the possible pairs of letters, there is at least one that lists all (for which a _pasuk_ exists). Alas, I don't remember which _sidur_ it is, but perhaps you can find it. I think it's an Israeli _sidur_.

Comment: Yes per the Sheimos Gittin in Shulchan Aruch it is spelled with a Samech.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3137/posuk-for-name-at-end-of-shemona-esrei/3145#3145

Comment: Duplicate of https://Judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29629 - see similarly https://Judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67451

Answer (score 7):

I used the Bar-Ilan Program to search for verses beginning with Samech and ending in Aleph. No hits.

Substituting a Sin for the Samech, we retrieved 8 hits, among them:

תהלים פרק פו פסוק ד

**שמח נפש עבדך כי אליך אדני נפשי אשא**

Substituting a Heh for the Aleph, we got 12 hits, among them:

במדבר פרק יד פסוק יט

**סלח נא לעון העם הזה כגדל חסדך וכאשר נשאתה לעם הזה ממצרים ועד הנה**

תהלים פרק מח פסוק יג

**סבו ציון והקיפוה ספרו מגדליה**

משלי פרק ד פסוק ח

**סלסלה ותרוממך תכבדך כי תחבקנה**

Answer (score 4):

Backing up Barry; using mechon-mamre's text and my own script.

There are, according to my script, no verses at all that start with a samech and end with an aleph.

If we follow Isaac's suggestion and allow Sins (*no, sinning is bad! Don't allow it!*). Okay here are some you probably *don't* want:

> שום תשים עליך מלך אשר יבחר יהוה אלהיך בו מקרב אחיך תשים עליך מלך לא תוכל לתת עליך איש נכרי אשר לא אחיך הוא
>
> Thou shalt certainly choose for yourself a king ... but not a foreigner.
>
> שפתי כסיל יבאו בריב ופיו למהלמות יקרא
>
> The lips of a fool cause fights

I agree with Barry, Psalms 86:4 is your best bet:

> Gladden the heart of your servant, as on You G-d I rely

Answer (score 3):

[It's also okay to have a posuk that actually contains the person's name](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43491&pgnum=78). So why not, for example, Tehillim 56:9: נֹדִי, סָפַרְתָּה-אָתָּה:    **שִׂימָה** דִמְעָתִי בְנֹאדֶךָ; הֲלֹא, בְּסִפְרָתֶךָ.

[I know the spelling is different, but if the point (as stated in the seforim) is to "help one remember one's name in the world-to-come," this would probably do the trick.]

Comment: Using the same equivalence, one could search for a verse that starts with שׂ and ends with א.

Answer (score 1):

Riffing on Dave's [idea](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9964/is-there-a-possuk-in-tanach-that-starts-with-a-samech-and-ends-with-a-aleph/9965#9965), the famous verse [Deut. 31](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9995):19 comes to mind:

> וְעַתָּה כִּתְבוּ לָכֶם אֶת הַשִּׁירָה הַזֹּאת וְלַמְּדָהּ אֶת בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל **שִׂימָהּ** בְּפִיהֶם לְמַעַן תִּהְיֶה לִּי הַשִּׁירָה הַזֹּאת לְעֵד בִּבְנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל:
>
> And now, write for yourselves this song, and teach it to the Children of Israel. Place it into their mouths, in order that this song will be for Me as a witness for the children of Israel.

Comment: Actually, that was the first one that came to mind, but the *mappik* was too disconcerting.