# Complete list of verses corresponding to people's names?

Tags: names, tanach, aleph-bet-letters

There is a custom to say a verse corresponding to ones name at the end of the Amidah, as a Segulah not to forget his name on the day of Judgement. There are several sources for this practice, including a bracketed Rashi ([Michah 6:9](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16192/showrashi/true#v9)) (this is quite possibly a later addition), some editions of the Kitzur Shelah ([Kitzur Shelah by R' Michel Epstein](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42571&pgnum=193)), and the Zohar. Read all about it [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20312&pgnum=388).

A verse that starts with the same letter as the beginning of your name, and ends with the same letter as your name ends is a verse that corresponds to your name.

I have seen many partial lists on verses corresponding to names, usually brought in various Siddurim (such as [this one](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20312&pgnum=389)). However, these lists usually just have verses for popular names, and are not an exhaustive list.

I'm looking for complete listing of every verse in the Tanach, grouped by first and last letter, starting from "א-א", and ending at "ת-ת"

Does such a list exist?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9964/is-there-a-possuk-in-tanach-that-starts-with-a-samech-and-ends-with-a-aleph/

Comment: I think it's in most Siddurim.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3137/posuk-for-name-at-end-of-shemona-esrei/3145#3145

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20613/reciting-a-posuk-representing-your-name-at-end-of-shemona-esrei-source/20616#comment48785_20616

Comment: @HachamGabriel, some _sidurim_ list one verse per pair of letters. I've never seen a _sidur_ list every verse in _Tanach_ or even _Chumash_.

Comment: Where in the Shlah is this? I seem to remember from last time this came up that no one could find it in the Shlah.

Comment: @DoubleAA: It says "Kitzur Shalah, end of the Sefer" From here: http://www.schechter.edu/responsa.aspx?ID=50 _ In 1693, Rabbi Yehiel Michal Epstein (Germany, d. 1706) published an abbreviation of that work in Fuerth entitled Kitzur Shnei Luhot Habrit which appeared in many different versions which are not identical. In at least one of the versions of the Kitzur Shelah (Lemberg, 1862 or 1864, fol. 101 at the end of the book, copied by Zlotnick, pp. 223-224 and Rozen, p. 154 = 144-145) we find the following paragraph:_

Comment: @DoubleAA: Last paragraph on this page: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42571&pgnum=193

Comment: I knew it was was in the kitzur shelah; I thought you found it in the shelah.

Comment: The Artscroll Siddur has the list for all names.

Comment: @Dennis, see my comment above.

Comment: @Mor: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15499/tehilim-hachida-in-the-order-of-the-aleph-bais/

Comment: If there are multiple pesukim for your name, can you just pick whichever one you want?

Comment: the עוז והדר siddur has a complete list

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the Bar Ilan responsa program, they have an option under פרפראות לתנ"ך where you can enter a name and it gives you all the corresponding verses. If you do not hav access to the program, let me know the name you want to check, and I will be happy to check for you.

Comment: The name Shabtai, seen here: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20312&pgnum=391 , has a verse that starts with a "Sin" I was wondering if there are any that start with a "Shin".

Comment: see following link for all the psukim: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Ips-MkGIS3dxhyS7FkW6JVPYWJxVFH6mvWI54l-W9cg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you, that is a great resource, I don't suppose they have it available online somewhere.

Comment: They have an online version of the program, but you need to pay subscription,  and I think this specific function doesn't appear there. It is a great program and worthwhile to buy. But I'll happily check any other name.

Comment: could you check starting with "peh" and ending with "kuf?

Comment: I apologize but the search yielded no results starting with a "peh" and ending with a "kuf". Let me know your name and I will search for a pasuk that perhaps connects to your name in a different way.

Comment: could you check for a posuk starting with "zayin" and ending with "lamed"

Comment: 1.  במדבר פרשת חקת פרק יט פסוק ב
זֹאת חֻקַּת הַתּוֹרָה אֲשֶׁר צִוָּה ה' לֵאמֹר דַּבֵּר אֶל בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל וְיִקְחוּ אֵלֶיךָ פָרָה אֲדֻמָּה תְּמִימָה אֲשֶׁר אֵין בָּהּ מוּם אֲשֶׁר לֹא עָלָה עָלֶיהָ עֹל: 

  2.  איוב פרק כ פסוק כט
זֶה חֵלֶק אָדָם רָשָׁע מֵאֱ-לֹהִים וְנַחֲלַת אִמְרוֹ מֵאֵל: פ 

  3.  איכה פרק ג פסוק כא
זֹאת אָשִׁיב אֶל לִבִּי עַל כֵּן אוֹחִיל: ס

Comment: Would you be so kind as to check for one starting with "shin" and ending with "hey"? THANK YOU

Comment: @SAH A full list is in the next answer. The easiest to remember is   שִׁיר הַשִּׁירִים אֲשֶׁר לִשְׁלֹמֹה

Comment: @OferLivnat I wonder how it is possible (ok, possible, but quite unlikely) that one combination is missing if there are 23,099 pesukim in such databases? (Also confused because I thought there were only like 9,000 verses in Tanach.)

Answer (score 8):

Ofer's [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/29637/5323) mentions that the Bar Ilan program has the complete list.

However, this program is costly, and I don't think that most people have it.

This functionality is also found in the free [Torat Emet](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/?downloads;1;) program, under the tab "שונות" ("*shonot*", "Miscellaneous"), as shown below.

Torat Emet's entire list is presented online [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150616061733/http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_00720_all.html).

[image: (a screenshot showing an option under the "shonot" tab selected for "chipus otiot katzeh", "search for boundary letters", and options for which books of Tanach to search in)]

Comment: I think that list only has 14,316(?) verses, whereas http://mordochai.tripod.com/tanach.html#top says there are 23,099?

Answer (score 5):

This article has a comprehensive list. It shows an example for every "first-letter/last-letter" combination:
[nifla-ot.co.il/articles/138.htm - web.archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140803215133/http://www.nifla-ot.co.il/articles/138.htm)

Answer (score 3):

I made an online search engine for all possible Gematrias, Roshei tevot and sofei tevot in Tanach over 5 years ago. The website address is [www.secretorah.com](http://www.secretorah.com).

If enough people are interested in the pasukim for their names please contact me and I will create this system too. This site is FREE and has no pictures on it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a decent-sized list [in the back of the Chabad siddur](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16091&st=&pgnum=1124&hilite=) ([*Siddur Tehillat Hashem*](https://store.kehotonline.com/prodinfo.asp?number=EP-STH.AEL)). The verses are listed by a name's beginning letter and  a range of ending letters.