# posuk for the name "Pearl" to say in shemone esre

Tags: names, tanach, aleph-bet-letters

I am searching for a possuk beginning with a pei and ending with a lamed, to say in Shemona Esre, for name Pearl. I have found one in tehillim perek 7, but would love a different one if at all possible.

Comment: find it here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29629/759

Comment: The Art Scroll siddur has a list at the back of the siddur. I do not have one here to use to check your particular letters.

Comment: You could try Bemidbar 13:7 if you don't mind reversing it: לְמַטֵּה יִשָּׂשכָר יִגְאָל בֶּן יוֹסֵף - otherwise your verse is it, besides for Loewian's 2nd suggestion.

Comment: We should probably not have 22×22 of these questions. Maybe it should be closed as a duplicate of the one @DoubleAA has linked to.

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_00720.html), it seems there may only (?!) be that verse from Psalms (7:3):

> **פ**ן יטרף כאריה נפשי פרק ואין מצי**ל**

If you're okay with the last word beginning with a ל (rather than ending with one), you could also use from אשת חיל (cited [here](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A7_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9C_%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA#.D7.90.D7.95.D7.AA_.D7.A4)):

> **פ**יה פתחה בחכמה ותורת חסד על **ל**שונה

Or, if you're also okay with it being a quote from the Shabbat prayer service rather than an actual verse in Tanach:

> **פ**אר וכבוד נותנים **ל**שמו

Comment: The pasuk in Tehillim is pointed to by the Art Scroll Hebrew English Sidur on page 926. Pages 922 - 926 have the list of letters used in the Ashkenaz nusach for all names with beginning and ending letters.