# Posuk for the name Golda

Tags: tefilla, names, segulah

What posuk for the name Golda is to be said at the end of Shemoneh Esrei?

I spell it with an aleph at the end and the Artscroll siddur doesn't have the gimmel, aleph combination.

Comment: Duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29629/ - see similarly https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67451/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Complete list of verses corresponding to people's names?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29629/complete-list-of-verses-corresponding-to-peoples-names)

Answer (score 9):

Here is a Posuk that starts with a Gimel and ends with an Aleph

איוב פרק-יג-ט"ז  גַּם הוּא לִי לִישׁוּעָה כִּי לֹא לְפָנָיו חָנֵף יָבוֹא

Here is a [nifty website](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_00720.html) where you can look up Pesukim that begin with a letter you desire and end with a letter you desire. There are some names that have a combo that does not exist. See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3137/posuk-for-name-at-end-of-shemona-esrei/3145#3145) for what one can do in such an instance.

Answer (score 3):

Following correct Yiddish orthography, 'Golda', in Hebrew letters, should be spelled with an 'א' at the end. This doesn't leave too many options for verses beginning & ending with those letters. No verses given in prayer books are mandated; they are suggestions which have become popular over the centuries. Job 13:16 is one possible option:

> גַּם-הוּא-לִי לִישׁוּעָה:    כִּי-לֹא לְפָנָיו, חָנֵף 
>   יָבוֹא.