# Is there a Possuk in Tanach that starts with a Pheh פ and ends with an Aleph א?

Tags: tefilla, tanach, shemoneh-esrei

In the list for names printed in many Siddurim, there is no Possuk for פיגא.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/50448/4940

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The list in the back of the Chabad siddur](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16091&st=&pgnum=1127) brings [Leviticus 2:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.2.5-6?ven=The_Contemporary_Torah,_Jewish_Publication_Society,_2006&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&aliyot=0):

> :פָּת֤וֹת אֹתָהּ֙ פִּתִּ֔ים וְיָצַקְתָּ֥ עָלֶ֖יהָ שָׁ֑מֶן מִנְחָ֖ה הִֽוא

> Break it into bits and pour oil on it; it is a meal offering.

I must say I don't find this verse to be rather inspiring or relevent to one's personal life.

Comment: I think it is extremely inspiring! There is much more depth after pshat.

Comment: I find it somewhat crummy ...