# Verse corresponding to name

Tags: tanach, names, aleph-bet-letters

I have checked other posts about this topic, but I can't find my answer:

I am writing a storyboard for a short film, and the main character is 'Binyamin ben Yosef.' Throughout the film, he memorizes his personal verse and tries to find its meaning and how it connects to his life.

I have read about 'personal verse' read before the Amidah. However, I cannot read Hebrew and do not understand how to go through the list of verses.

What is a verse reference that connects with בִּנְיָמִין?

Also, is there one for אֶסְתֵּר? Or  הדסה?

Comment: It's a dupe but I don't find it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, @kouty?

Comment: There is already a post with a similar question, already answered

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29629/9215

Comment: I don't know how to read Hebrew and couldn't understand the list.

Comment: Ahhh sorry @Coding4el

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have read about 'personal verse' read before the Amidah.

The custom I am familiar with is to recite it at the *end* of the 'Amidah by the יהיו לרצון.

> What is a verse reference that connects with בִּנְיָמִין?

ב-ן:    "בָּרוּךְ ה' לְעוֹלָם אָמֵן וְאָמֵן" (תהילים פט נג)

Blessed be the LORD for evermore. Amen, and Amen. (Psalms 89:53)

> Also, is there one for אֶסְתֵּר?

א-ר:   "אֵלֶּה בָרֶכֶב וְאֵלֶּה בַסּוּסִים וַאֲנַחְנוּ בְּשֵׁם ה' אֱ-לֹהֵינוּ נַזְכִּיר" (תהילים כ ח)

Some trust in chariots, and some in horses; but we will make mention of the name of the LORD our God. (Psalms 20:8)

> Or הדסה?

ה-ה:   "הִנֵּה אֵ-ל יְשׁוּעָתִי אֶבְטַח וְלֹא אֶפְחָד כִּי עָזִּי וְזִמְרָת יָ-הּ ה' וַיְהִי לִי לִישׁוּעָה"
(ישעיהו יב ב)

Behold, God is my salvation; I will trust, and will not be afraid; for GOD the LORD is my strength and song; and He is become my salvation.' (Isaiah 12:2)

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20140803215133/http://www.nifla-ot.co.il/articles/138.htm)